# Let div fill up space next to centered container

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage containing a centered container with content and I want to display a logo next to it.

The layout is as following: div - container. Where the container is centered and the div lef of the container needs to fill out the width left on the screen.

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
#container {
 width: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 min-height: 100%;
}

<div id="container">

</div>
<div id="lef">
</div>
```

A jsfiddle with this code is available on http://jsfiddle.net/7QJQn/

Comment: can you explain it more clear?

Comment: take a look at my fiddle in the answer field.

Comment: I guess your are right. To bad css can't do complex calculations like width:100%-400px;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the option that comes closed

**http://jsfiddle.net/7QJQn/4/**

I think that the best solution for doing something like this is just using javascript / jQuery.

Comment: I think that the best solution for doing something like this is just using javascript / jQuery.

Comment: The problem of this one is that the container needs to be a fixed width and this one is in percentages maybe @andrea is right and this is only possible with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which browsers you wish to support, you could use calc().

Basically, you want 50% of the viewport width (50vw) minus half of width of #container (so you're measuring from the center of your #container and you use half of all the values) - I'm assuming that you're OK with absolute positioning #lef to the viewport to keep it to the right?

CSS ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/7QJQn/46/)):

```
#lef {
  background-color:yellow;
  width:calc(50vw - 100px);
  height:20px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
#lef{
  float:left
}
```

And change the order of the divs in the html, like this:

```
<div id="lef"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: after he changes the order of the divs ?

Comment: tried it in http://jsfiddle.net/2KQTb/ but the yellow bar will only appear on top but will still take 100% width. Because the container div isn't floated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should wrap your markup in a wrapper `div` so elements stay tight.
I made some changes, take a look:

```
 <div id="wrapper">

  <div id="lef">

  </div>


  <div id="container">

  </div>

</div>
```

​
And the css:

```
 html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;

}

#wrapper{

width: 360px;

}

#container {
 width: 200px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 height: 100px;
 background-color:red;
}
#lef {
background-color:yellow;
width: 160px;;
height:100px;
float: left;
}​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7QJQn/5/)

Comment: The proble of this one is that left is fixed widht and it needs to fill 100%-200px instead.

Answer (score 0):

If using flexbox is an option, you can do this with the flex-grow property:

With the following markup

```
<div class="main-row">
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="row-content">Fixed width centered div</div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

you need to set flex-grow: 1 on the filler divs. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ifourh/gnhxz97w/1/).