# Using DIV instead of TABLE but DIV width does not fill available space

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-image

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="background-image:url('../images/navi/top-red.png'); float:left;"></div>
<div style="width:180px; float:left;"><img src="/images/navi/logo.jpg" style="width:178px; height:62px; float:right; border:0;" /></a></div>
<div style="width:800px; float:left; background-image:url('../images/navi/top-black.png');"><ul id="topnav" style="">NAVI LINKS</ul></div>
<div style="background-image:url('../images/navi/top-black.png');float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is...
the width:180px and width:800px= 980px is centered on browser all the time
the left and right have no content (only background gradient image with FLUID width):

> --------------------------------- width: 100% browser -----------------------------
>
> |top-red.png FLUID | width:180px-LOGO.jpg | width:800px-NAVI LINKS | top-black.png FLUID|
>
> --------------------------------- width: 100% browser -----------------------------

I am trying to build a full width 100% top navi menu for my website.

- center content is fixed 980px
- center content consists of a) logo image and b) navi links
- left space is filled with top-red.png as background-image
- right space is filled with top-black.png as background-image

I been trying to use 3 and 4 DIVs (4 divs if logo and navi each 1 DIV) to construct but the 1st left-most div WIDTH does not fill up all available space and the background-image only spawn a little bit.
Eg. If I type a string of words in the DIV, the background-image will extend ONLY to the length of the string of words.

I gave up and eventually succeeded using TABLE tag (see below)
The '1st TD' will auto fill all avail WIDTH touching to the '2nd TD'
Can see this:

[image]

..but I still hope someone here can enlighten me on how to do it using DIV tag though!

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-image:url('../images/navi/top-red.png'); height:62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height:62px; width:180px; padding-right:10px;"><a href="/"><img src="/images/navi/logo.jpg" alt="LOGO IMAGE" style="width:178px; height:62px; border:0;" /></a></td>
    <td style="height:62px; width:800px; background-image:url('../images/navi/top-black.png')">NAVI MENU</td>
    <td style="background-image:url('../images/navi/top-black.png'); height:62px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There definitely must be a way to style your menu as you want using divs and lists, tables really shouldn't be used for styling/positiong purposes, can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or post here you're attempt with div tags. Also I would addvise against the use of background images for menus, you can now use CSS3 to create gradients that are supported on almost all major browsers

Comment: Please provide your codes via fiddle or post here, we'll help you

Comment: posted on my question TOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here's my attempt, I used a `.container` element for the 980px centered part and then I used the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to create the fluid parts and positioned them absolutely. Also I used CSS3 gradients instead of background images (I omitted the gradient code here in the answer to save space)

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5LUv/15/embedded/result/)**

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar"> 
            <a href="#" id="brand">
                <img id="logo" src ="http://placehold.it/180x50"/>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 62px;
    position: relative;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 9999px; /* a large number to fill remaining space*/
    height: 62px;
    top: 0;
}
.container:after {
    left: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    /* + black gradient background*/
}
.container:before {
    right: 100%;
    background-color: #AF0B00;
    /* + red gradient background*/
}
#brand {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 62px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    right: 100%;
    background-color: #AF0B00;
    /* + red gradient background*/
}
#logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar .nav:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content:'';
    height: 62px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}
.navbar .nav {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 790px;/*800-10 of logo padding*/
    height: 62px;
    background-color: #000000;
    /* + black gradient background*/
}
.navbar .nav li {
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 62px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.navbar .nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 18px;
}
```

Comment: i was still looking around for solution... was reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384271/let-div-fill-up-space-next-to-centered-container which similar problem to me. i lost hope when comments said 'you can not do that' but heck you just just did =) i testing the code now. 1st load and looks like what i needed. i will go read and digest the code now!

Comment: width: 9999px; /* a large number to fill remaining space*/ <= i changed to 100% width and it still looks ok to me. any reason why u use 9999px instead of 100% width??

Comment: @busterSg the only issue I found with using 100% is that if you zoom out enough you'll see that it doesn't cover all the width of the page since 100% means the width of the container (980px) so at max you'd have 980 x 3 = 2940px, so better to play it safe

Comment: i can scroll rightwards even the horizontal scroll-bar is not visible so the wide area of white space on the right of container still remains actually. maybe this is not technical possible without find the on-the-fly width of user browser since i have 2 fluid width left/right ?

Comment: @busterSg check this update http://jsfiddle.net/M5LUv/24/embedded/result/, I made some changes to prevent horizontal scrolling, just note that I'm using the HTML5 tag <header> and you would need to add html5shiv to allow support from IE < 9, of course you can also change the tag to a normal <div>